Basic apt issues
I am just trying to install some basic packages and continue to run into the following errors when doing anything apt related:
Ign:91 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Err:92 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main arm64 Packages     
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80] 
Fetched 338 kB in 7s (48.8 kB/s)                                               
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-aarch64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'aarch64'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-aarch64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'aarch64'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-aarch64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture 
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-aarch64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'aarch64'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I shortened for brevity, there are probably about 25 of these errors. I made a backup of my old sources.list and generated a new one, that made no difference. I also made a backup of the PPAs and had those refs regenerated as well to no avail. Any ideas on why so many references to arm64 repos? I am on an aarch64 machine running Ubuntu 22.04.4LTS.

You probably need ports.ubuntu.com (or one of its mirrors) in place of archive.ubuntu.com for all ARM variants - see related Ubuntu Jammy (in WSL): adding armhf arch, can't find packages or repositories

This is true even if I am not on an arm system? Part of why I am so confused is why it keeps auto-generating arm dependency links when I am not on an ARM machine

AFAIK aarch64 is arm64 - see for example AArch64: Naming conventions

You're right my bad, I'm getting arm, aarch, and amd64 all mixed up. Ill try changing the urls and see how that goes.

@steeldriver You have answered the question in your comments.

To download the missing index files, you need to use ports as said @steeldriver in his comment.
Edit your /etc/apt/sources.list as follows:
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy partner

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy partner
